# respuesta gulp-util

Tags: git, gulp, git-bash

`git bash` me devuelve el siguiente mensaje, ¿que significa?

```
$ npm ls gulp-util
infante@1.0.0 C:\Users\infante
`-- gulp-install@1.1.0
  `-- gulp-util@3.0.8
```

Comment: Diego Alejo agrega mas información a tu pregunta para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte, como por ejemplo que acciones haces para que aparezca ese error.

Answer (score 1):

`$ npm ls gulp-util` significa:

**n**ode **p**ackage **m**anager **l**i**s**tame las versiones y dependencias del módulo `gulp-util`

y la respuesta es:
tienes la version 3.0.8 de`gulp-util` que depende del módulo `gulp-install` cuya versión es 1.1.0 y todo esto está manejado por la version `1.0.0` de npm desde la carpeta `C:\Users\infante`